# HTML/Javascript: Display:none copy and paste issue

Tags: javascript, html

I have read a number of posts on this topic but haven't found a solution to my particular situation.  Perhaps there isn't one but I figured I would ask.

I have a report being generated in HTML from a powershell script, its being dumped to a folder on a server (NOT A WEBSERVER, so no PHP or any fun stuff available)

The report can then be filtered by error type or information.  This is done by display:none 'ing various elements, wether they be tr's or div's.. Javascript Below

These filters can hide a variety of things making hundreds of possible combinations of different elements possible.  So moving them or removing and creating them using DOM's would rough because I dont know how I would tell it where to put the element back.

I need to make it so that a filtered report can be copy pasted to send out in emails.  Any Ideas?

```
    function showhide(button) {
        if (button.value == 'hide') {
            var arr = document.getElementsByName(button.name +'tr');
            var length = arr.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                arr[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
            document.getElementById(button.name +'div').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='showhide(this)' name='" + button.name  + "' value='show'>Show " + button.name  + "</a>";
        }
        else if (button.value == 'show') {
            document.getElementById(button.name +'div').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='showhide(this)' name='" + button.name  + "' value='hide'>Hide " + button.name  + "</a>";
            var arr = document.getElementsByName(button.name  +'tr');
            var length = arr.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                arr[i].style.display = '';
            }
        }
    }
```

Solution:

```
function showhide(button) {
        var seeMe = document.getElementById('visible');
        seeMe.innerHTML = ' ';
        if (button.value == 'hide') {
            var arr = document.getElementsByName(button.name +'tr');
            var length = arr.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                arr[i].style.display = 'none';
                arr[i].name = 'h';
            }
            document.getElementById(button.name +'div').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='showhide(this)' name='" + button.name  + "' value='show'>Show " + button.name  + "</a>";
        }
        else if (button.value == 'show') {
            document.getElementById(button.name +'div').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='showhide(this)' name='" + button.name  + "' value='hide'>Hide " + button.name  + "</a>";
            var arr = document.getElementsByName(button.name  +'tr');
            var length = arr.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                arr[i].style.display = '';
                arr[i].name = 's';
            }
        }
        var search = document.getElementById('hidden').children;
        for(var i = 0; i < search.length; i++) {
            seeMe.appendChild(search[i].cloneNode(true));
        }
        var paras = document.getElementById('visible').getElementsByTagName('*');
        for(var i = 0; i < paras.length; i++) {
            if (paras[i].name == 'h') {
                paras[i].parentNode.removeChild(paras[i]);
                i--
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Open new window, grab the report element, copy only elements with display!= none into the new window's element and use that as your email-to page content? it's ugly but it seems workable.

Comment: If it were me doing this daily I would simply have the javascript remove the elements all together and just refresh if I screwed up, but its not going to be me :(

Comment: sure, that's why I am suggesting using a email-to page that receives a copy of the HTML to be sent.

Comment: OH I miss read your post... ya that could work, but I was hoping for a solution that wouldn't require me to convince the users not to highlight and to use a button instead, because they will likely ignore that comment and keep sending me bug reports

Comment: you could pump all of the data into a document fragment and use the same copy logic to construct the 'live' view when a filter has been applied, I suppose.

Comment: I wont lie... dont follow ya there

Comment: When you first apply any of the filters, copy all of the HTML elements from the page into a document fragment object, manipulate their visibility there, then copy only the visible objects back into the DOM. Changing filters is applied in the fragment and then copied back.

Comment: OH nice.. ill give that a shot

Comment: Tetsujin, can you please post your suggestion as an actual response so that I can mark it as correct... thanks

Comment: If you have a solution to the issue, please post that as an answer, don't edit the question. Only add it to the question if the code has a problem with it that you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first apply any of the filters, copy all of the HTML elements from the page into a document fragment object, manipulate their visibility there, then copy only the visible objects back into the DOM. Changing filters is applied in the fragment and then copied back.

Comment: This worked however because some of my hidden elements are nested I took a slightly different approach and copied EVERYTHING back then deleted all hidden elements from the main.

Comment: Glad I could help, TetraFlash!